# Each day, Ms. Vasquez divides her 15 students into groups of 3. What is the probability that Lisa, Prank and Maria will be in the same group today?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Each day, Ms. Vasquez divides her 15 students into groups of 3. What is the probability that Lisa, Prank and Maria will be in the same group today? Express your answer as a common fraction.

This is from a timed competition. I did $\frac{3*2*1}{15 \choose 3}$.

I don't think this is correct. Is there a faster method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lisa's group are two random other persons from the $15\setminus$Lisa. The probability that this pair consists of Prank and Maria is $${1\over{14\choose2}}={1\over91}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

Lisa must be in some group.  There are $14$ spots left, and $2$ of them are in the same group as Lisa, so assuming that the teacher assigns students to groups uniformly at random, the probability that Prank will be in the same group as Lisa is $\frac2{14}$. Can you finish it?

Comment: $1 * 4/14 * 3/13$? but what if she chooses them all at once?

Comment: @cheemcheem Makes no difference.  Let M be the event that Mark is in the same group as Lisa and P the event that Prank is in the same group as Lisa.  Then $\Pr(M\cap P)=\Pr(M)\Pr(P|M)$.

Comment: It is divided into 5 groups of 3, not 3 groups of 5.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I must be getting cross-eyed.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac {1}{_{15}C_{3}}$,  Because all the different possibilities for the group containing the specific $3$ students are ${_{15}C_{3}}$ . Only one of these possibilities will turn out to be favorable.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect since there are five groups which could contain Lisa, Prank, and Maria.  Keep in mind Ms. Vasquez divides her students into five groups of three.  Any one of those five groups could contain Lisa, Prank, and Maria.